# Push Notification does not work on iOS 10 via TestFlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios10

I have came to know that push notification settings have been changed in iOS10. I have done the required steps and deployed the application via Xcode, then tested and the push notification worked. Then I deployed it on the TestFlight and asked my friend to test it, but it does not work.

I wonder what I am missing in my following implementation. It seems me that something related with development vs. production issue but I do not know what I am doing wrong or missing something?

I have used the following command to generate pem file.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in aps_production.cer -out certificate.pem
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in Certificates.p12 -out p12Certificates.pem
cat certificate.pem p12Certificates.pem > apns_cert.pem
```

In my **apns.php**, I am calling

// Open a connection to the APNS server

```
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, 
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

I have added the following in the Info.plist

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```

**Capabilities --> Push Notification** set it to **ON**

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert                                                                                               | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge                                                                                                | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")){
        UNUserNotificationCenter *notifiCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        notifiCenter.delegate = self;
        [notifiCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
            if( !error ){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }
        }];
    }
    return YES;

}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    NSData *someData = deviceToken;
    NSString *someDataHexadecimalString = [someData hexadecimalString];
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", someDataHexadecimalString);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someDataHexadecimalString forKey:@"apnsToken"]; //save token to resend it if request fails
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"]; // set flag for request status
}

//foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}

@end
```

Comment: Why in your openssl command are you referring to aps_development.cer but your asp-environment is production?

Comment: @MikeTaverne, I have fixed. Please ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

1:make .pem file of live APNS certificate.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

2:make provisioning profile on Ad hoc mode then Upload on testFlight

Comment: when you will make distribution provisioning profile there will option of Ad Hoc that will check your push on  live mode.

Comment: I want to test the push notification such that application is on the Apple Store.

Comment: On distribution .pem file you can check by only Ad hoc not not in distribution mode. and use this http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info for push notification